# Regex matching a multiline, mixed case string with whitespace in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to guarantee that a field in our CMS contains *only* an unordered list. For example,

```
<ul>
    <li>
        This is our first bullet point
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm using the following to match this:

```
String pattern = "^<ul>(<li>.*</li>)+</ul>$";
Regex rgx = new Regex(@pattern, 
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace 
    | RegexOptions.Multiline 
    | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if(rgx.IsMatch(controlValidationValue)) { ... }
```

This works when the html is all on one line, but fails as soon as I get line breaks or whitespace - which may happen, as our CMS uses a rich text plugin to create the html.

I've tried using a bitwise AND (instead of OR), and played with `RegexOptions.SingleLine` but can't get to the bottom of the problem.

Any/all help appreciated!

Comment: Use `RegexOptions.Singleline` and lazy `.*?`.

Comment: Thanks @stribizhev - Singleline as well as or instead of Multiline? Not sure if they're mutually exclusive

Comment: They are not exclusive. Multiline forces `^` and `$` match at the beginning/end of lines, and singleline just forces `.` to match a newline.

Comment: this should work: `^<ul>(\s*<li>[\w\W]*<\/li>\s*)+<\/ul>$`

Comment: Thanks everyone - I struggled to get Regex to work with the newlines, even with your suggestions - so ended up going with the HTMLAgilityPack suggestion from @TimSchmelter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general i would use `HtmlAgilityPack` to parse HTML instead of regex.

```
string html = @"<ul>
    <li>
        This is our first bullet point
    </li>
</ul>";

var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html.Trim());  // Trim to remove leading or trailing spaces if that's possible
bool valid = doc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes.Count == 1 
          && doc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes[0].Name == "ul";
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, we'd originally talked about using HtmlAgilityPack but thought Regex would be more simple. Obviously not!